# Double buffering in BlackBerry?

Tags: graphics, blackberry, drawing, doublebuffered

Do we need to do double buffering in BlackBerry while rendering our paint code or does BlackBerry handle that? If we need to do that ourselves, how do we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like Richard said,

> Although there is a need to perform explicit double buffering in Mobile Information Device Profile (MIDP) applications, the BlackBerry user interface (UI) implementation is inherently double-buffered. This means there is no need to perform your own double buffering of UI images. Essentially, all drawing functions in net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics objects are drawn to an off-screen bitmap by the system. When you call for a repaint of the screen, it draws this off-screen bitmap instead of sequentially painting the screen. This same drawing paradigm is true for all fields and field managers within the Blackberry UI.

[BlackBerry KB - How do I perform double buffering using the BlackBerry UI?](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/javaknowledge/userInterface/kpa0203162151.shtml)